# Why does a page create a scrollbar when browser is resized?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, scrollbar

I am noticing a weird visual bug when a browser is resized and another element piece (`Menu`) is added based on a boolean variable. How the basic page is laid out:

```
<div className="mainDiv">
  {
    !isEnabled &&
    <Menu className="menuTab" style={{height: "60px"}} ... >
        {
          <MenuItem ... />
        }
    </Menu>
  }
  <Splitter className="splitter">
    <div>
    // More custom divs and such in here
    </div>
    <div className="graph">
      {
        isEnabled && <customD3Graph ... />
      }
      {
        !isEnabled && <customD3Graph2 ... />
      }
  </Spitter>

</div>
```

So, we basically have a `Stepper` at the top of the page to "route" to different views. This view shown above represents two "routes" that a user can click. They will generally click the first route where the `Menu` item is *not* displayed, then they will click the second route where the `Menu` displays.

The first view of the page without the menu does not create a scrollbar when resized, but when the user clicks to go to the second route of the same page just with different data and the menu, resizing creates a scrollbar. However, if the user manually reloads/refreshes the page and then resizes the browser, no scrollbar is created. This *only* happens when going from the first route view to the second view.

Below is some CSS we have applied to the above HTML code for layouts that may be useful.

```
.mainDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;

  // This calculation is done for some titles/banners above this shown in a different JS file.
  height: calc(100% - 85px - 50px);
  width: 100%;
}

.splitter {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  order: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.mainDiv:has(.menuTab) > .splitter {
  // Calculated to account for that 'Menu' that would appear
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
}
```

Another CSS file that controls the custom D3 graphs has the below CSS:

```
.graph {
  // Set this to less than 100% because 100% auto-created a scrollbar right away 
  height: 98%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Then lastly, those custom D3 files both have JavaScript that returns:

```
<div style={{height: "100%", width: "100%", margin: "0px"}}>
  // custom components
</div>
```

I hope I have provided enough information but not too much for overload to help find what may be going on.

A screenshot of the error is below - the outer scrollbar should ideally not be there, as we have inner scrollbars for the `Splitter` contents to be individually scrolled.

[image: Scrollbar Issue]

---

Clarification:

I have noticed that the scroll issue is relevant to the custom D3 graph heights. For example, when I changed the height of the custom components from `98%` to `50%` or `75%`, the scrollbar appeared when I shrunk the browser to that part. Because the graphs were smaller than the size of their container, their bottom cut-off was visible in the `Splitter`, so when the browser shrunk to that link or just higher, then the outer scrollbar appeared.

Comment: It does seem adding `overflow-y: hidden` to `.mainDiv { ... }` CSS code does get the scrollbar hidden. However, I am not sure if that is the best solution to use or what the underlying issue may be, since it does seem when the scrollbar appears that there are no other elements extending in the empty space created at the bottom of the page.

Comment: On a responsive site were multiple elements can overflow it is possible to get a bit of chicken and egg syndrome, as you have found setting overflow can help here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Keith. I am newer to web development and joined this project with much of the entire system already built. So needless to say, trying to go back in and fix these pieces that are so embedded has been a bit confusing to learn!

Comment: Another solution seems to be to just break out the two separate components into different files instead of re-rendering the same file. I will keep this question up a bit longer in case another answer is given, otherwise I will close it.